# Что такое "электронная трассировка"?

Tags: алгоритм, терминология

Что такое «электронная трассировка» и в чем заключается её смысл и алгоритм?

Дополнение: область знаний-математическая логика. К коду отношения не имеет, нужно определение, алгоритм, пример применения.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста ваш вопрос. Гугл такого понятия не знает. Нечто, сочетающее в себе термины "электронная трассировка" и "алгоритм" находится только в [архиве какой-то фидошной эхи](http://www.frozenfido.ru/ru.algorithms/27853b1ebf94.html). Укажите хотя бы примерно область знаний, из которой взято это понятие.

Comment: @fori1ton это проверка на планарность графа

Comment: @PashaPash, а у меня вот сложилось впечатление, что не проверка на планарность, а укладка графа (вероятно, имеется ввиду разводка печатных плат). В любом случае, стоит дождаться уточнения автора вопроса.

Comment: @fori1ton укладка графа - это и есть планарность. граф планарен == его можно уложить на плоскость

Comment: http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/view.php/theory/graph-coloring-layout/layout-2004

Comment: область знаний по курсу:математическая логика и теория алгоритмов. гугл сама весь перерыла, даже и предположить не могу что рассказывать по данному вопросу, если попадется...

Comment: @Melia1033 если спросят - начинайте издалека. например, с того, что Понтрягин ослеп в 14 лет ... и пока дойдете до алгоритма - всем надоест, и в детали алгоритма никто не будет вникать.

Comment: @PashaPash смешно)спс за совет)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смысл электронной трассировки - проверка на возможность напечатать конктерную электронную схему на плоскости. Для этого граф, состоящий из вершин-компонентов и ребер-соединений, должен быть плоским.

Плоский граф — это граф, нарисованный таким образом, что его ребра не пересекаются. Говорят, что граф допускает плоскую укладку, если его можно нарисовать как плоский. Также плоские графы называют планарными.

По [теореме Понтрягина-Куратовского](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE): Граф планарен тогда и только тогда, когда он не содержит подграфов, гомеоморфных K<sub>5</sub> (звезда) или K<sub>3,3</sub> (три дома, три колодца).

Для определения планарности графа можно использовать [гамма-алгоритм](http://rain.ifmo.ru/cat/data/theory/graph-coloring-layout/layout-2006/article.pdf). Или попробовать вручную перебрать все подграфы и проверить их на гомеоморфность.